# Test job cancellation on Android with Coroutines

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-testing

I'm working on a RN library where `MyClass`is some kind of `View` and I inject a coroutineScope in order to be able to test it. The code looks similar to the following one:

```
class MyClass(scope:CoroutineScope){
  
  private lateinit var myJob : Job?
  
  fun myMethod() {
    myJob = scope.launch {
      val someObject = getSomeObject()
      if (someObject != null && isActive) {
        doSomething()
      }
    }
  }
  
  fun onDestroy(){
    cancelJob()
  }

  private fun cancelJob() {
    if (myJob != null && myJob!!.isActive) {
      myJob!!.cancel()
      myJob = null
    }
  }
}
```

And I have two questions about it.
First I'd like to write a unit to verify that when the coroutineScope is cancelled, then the job.cancel is called.

And my second question is: is it a best practice to keep a reference of the job inside a a class? wouldn't that produce a memory leak? But I want to keep track of the job to cancel it and not execute `doSomething()` when the coroutine scope is cancelled.

Comment: After some research I found this https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2379 and I tried to use TestScope from Kotlin 1.6.10 but I don't know how exactly I should manage or whether it makes sense test Scope or job cancellation. I'm trying to call TestScope.coroutineContext.job.cancel() but since I use the test scope to run the test and I was obtaining an exception TestScopeImpl was cancelled
kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: TestScopeImpl was cancelled job=TestScope[test ended]. I also tried to run the test itself in another scope. What I wonder is does it makes sense?